# AWS CLI Command Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to get a count of total instances in my account so I ran the below command:

> get-discovered-resource-counts

But its getting me the below error:

> 'get-discovered-resource-counts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You should start with the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-using.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed the AWS CLI (verify by executing `aws --version`) and that you have [configured your access key id and secret access key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html) correctly, you should be able to execute it:

```sh
aws configservice get-discovered-resource-counts
```

Side note, the command will only return the instances in the current region. If you would like to see the number of instances in another region you can provide it using the `--region` parameter. For example, if you would like to know the current status in the Ireland region of your account, you use `eu-west-1` as value:

```sh
aws configservice get-discovered-resource-counts --region eu-west-1
```

More info in the AWS CLI reference: [aws configservice get-discovered-resource-counts](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configservice/get-discovered-resource-counts.html).

Comment: I used the above command but its returning me "0". How can I filter to return me the count of ec2 instances in my environment.

Comment: @SarahKhan Two suggestions come to mind. First verify that you use the correct region by providing the `--region` flag mentioned above. Secondly, verify that you are querying the correct account, for example using the [aws sts get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) command.